What happens if a client involved in active litigation disappears?
So, say a lawyer is representing someone in an ongoing civil case. Initial documents have been filed, maybe one or two motions have happened. However, the client, because of some reason (lets say a criminal investigation linked to the civil case, or evidence of a crime uncovered during proceedings) decides to go on the run. What would happen in this case?
Also, in this case, the client wouldn't be communicating with their lawyer anymore, or paying any bills, since they're obviously not going to be showing up in court anymore anyway, given that they'd probably get arrested upon arriving, and you're not going to be paying someone to represent you anymore if you've already abandoned the whole thing.
So, what would happen in this case? I'd assume it'd end in a default judgement against the client, but how exactly? Would the lawyer withdraw or be required to keep representing knowing that they'll never see any pay for it? How would court orders be served?
I assume the lawyer needs to make a good faith effort to serve them (email + voicemail?) and show records to the judge when the client doesn't show on the court date the judge set, and the judge then gives a default judgement against them? Is this correct? Are there any additional complications/requirements?

The lawyer can continue to represent the client actively, in hope of receiving future contact from the client, or can ask the court for permission to withdraw from representing the client, following local rules regarding the procedure for filing a motion to withdraw. There must be an ethically permissible reason to withdraw (set out in the rules for professional ethics) and loss of contract would be one of them. But this doesn't have to be stated very specifically in the motion.
Even if a lawyer is not getting paid, this is not automatically grounds for allowing the lawyer to withdraw.

I'd assume it'd end in a default judgement against the client, but how
exactly?

No. A default judgment happens when the defendant files nothing in the case. By filing initial documents, the client didn't default.
Plenty of cases are tried to conclusion without the client ever having to appear, perhaps through motion practice, or perhaps through other means. I've handled several cases for clients who are dead, and while I have the executor to give me guidance, obviously, the client can't testify in the case.

Would the lawyer withdraw or be required to keep representing knowing
that they'll never see any pay for it?

This is up to the lawyer and the court handling any withdrawal motion.

How would court orders be served?

When someone is represented by a lawyer, papers are served upon them by delivering them to the lawyer.

So in that case, if a lawyer can't contact the client for instructions, how do they proceed? Do they just go with "what wins me the case" and take standard steps in that direction? Also, what happens if the case is already ongoing and the lawyer managed to withdraw? Since at that point it seems nobody can serve the client anymore, and there's nobody to represent them (assuming they don't remotely hire a new lawyer).

"Do they just go with "what wins me the case" and take standard steps in that direction?" Unless the client had said otherwise in advance. "what happens if the case is already ongoing and the lawyer managed to withdraw?" Usually, the client loses, but the other side still has to prove their case to the judge, the loss isn't autoamtic.
